# Expanding/shrinking one container horizontally and vertically while others remain fixed in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a header bar and footer bar for an app that is a static height.  I also have a content section between that is a Stack that has a primary base image and therefore has a static height/width ratio.

I'd like for the content to be able to resize dynamically based on the platform screen dimensions it's running within, but not stretch the image and maintain the height/width ratio.  In other words, if the screen is one that has a "long" height, then it should have gutters on the left and right and look like this:

[Long Height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZj6C.png)

But, if the screen has a "short" height, the gutters should appear on the top and the bottom, like this:

[Short Height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNpna.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Column` like this:

```
      Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: mWidth,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Image.network(
              "imageUrl",
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: mWidth,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

I hope it is useful for you.